# Why the toast message is getting printed twice?

Tags: java, android, android-button

When I'm comparing the values of `duration2` and `duration4`, the Toast message I'm using is printing twice, although the answer/message is correct. I don't know why it's happening. Please tell me how to fix this.

```
Button b1, b2, b3;
long duration, duration2, duration3, duration4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                duration=System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            else if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                duration2= System.currentTimeMillis()-duration;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
    b2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                duration3=System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            else if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                duration4= System.currentTimeMillis()-duration3;
            }

            if(duration4<duration2) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(duration4>duration2) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Too Slow Man", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are toasting inside the onTouchEvent. There is an ACTION_DOWN and an ACTION_UP.

I suppose a simple fix would be to store a boolean value to say you've shown the message already and add that to an if statement around the duration check